# Pass setting data from database to layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to pass data from de setting table from the database to my layout view.

How do I get it done?

```
$item = Setting::find(1);
return view($this->controller.'/show')->with( 'item', $item);
```

Solution:

```
public function boot() {
    if( !isset( $_SESSION['adminTitle'] ) ){
        $item = Setting::find(1);
        $item = $item->toArray();
        $_SESSION['adminTitle'] = $item['title'];
        $_SESSION['adminEmail'] = $item['email'];
        $_SESSION['adminLogo'] = $item['logo'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply this?:

```
// File app/Http/Controllers/ExampleController.php

//

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
  public function show() 
  {
    //

    $setting = Setting::find(1);
    return view('example', ['setting' => $setting]);
  }

}
```

Within the Blade view:

```
<!-- resources/views/example.blade.php -->

{{ $setting->title }}
{{ $setting->logo }}
...
```

---

But, if you want to share settings between **all** your views, you can add this middleware:

```
// File app/Http/Middleware/ViewShareSettingMiddleware

//

class ViewShareSettingMiddleware
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
     $setting = Setting::find(1);
     view()->share('setting', $setting);
     return $next($request);
  }

}
```

Comment: That's also a solution, but then you always get the data from the dbase and not from sessions

Comment: @Bas your question is: "Pass setting data from *database to layout*". If you don't want to load them from db each time you can try to use some caching system (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/cache).

Comment: @Bas Why do you need to get them from session and not directly from database?

Comment: thats true, once, but your solution is also good. I have not worked yet with cache. I will try that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create your view in:

> \resources\views\

Example: `\resources\views\index.blade.php`

```
$data['item'] = Setting::find(1);
return view('index')
            ->with( $data);
```

Or

```
$item = Setting::find(1);
return view('index', compact('item');
```

View: `{{$item}}`

Comment: But where do i have to declare it? In the AppServiceProvider? And how?

Comment: Check my edit, look like you dont have any layout view.

Comment: I have, resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php But where do i have to put the $item = Setting::find(1); etc etc

Comment: Oh, you must create your controller and route to handler method from your view.

Comment: Creative solution above, do you think there is a better one?